# Django: OR queries with dynamic field names

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a value and want to get all instances having the value in one or more column. And to make this a bit more complex, the field list is dynamic.

So, what I have is: `['field1', 'field2', 'field3', ...]`

What I need is: `Q(field1='value') | Q(field2='value') | Q(field3='value') | ...`

How can I get this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `**` dictionary-to-kw-args expansion:

```
q = Q()
for field in fields:
    q = q | Q(**{field: "value"})
```

(as `Q()` yield a `Q` which "does nothing", as far as I can tell)

Comment: Thanks for the update, because less than two can definitly happen.

Comment: No problem. In fact, I've taken out the original, as `reduce` is generally a bad idea, and the newer version is basically better in every way.