# In Django, I seem to really need dynamic field names. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: django, database-schema

I'm new to Django, and in my current project I have a 'Noun' model with a bunch of 12 parallel-feeling fields: 'nominativeSingular', 'vocativeSingular', 'ablativePlural', etc.

I often seem to want to get the relevant property for a given Noun from some combination of strings ('accusative', 'plural') and while I could handwrite a 12-item dictionary, that seems really horribly inelegant.

The question here: [Django: OR queries with dynamic field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340106/django-or-queries-with-dynamic-field-names) suggests using "** dictionary-to-kw-args" - is this indeed what I want here? If so, might it be possible to explain how it might work in this case? Alternatively, is this whole thing really a result of bad database design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! What I wanted here was getattr, which does exactly this, and is a Python affair rather than a Django one.

This page explained it helpfully: http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm - essentially, these lines are equivalent:

```
value = obj.attribute;
```

and

```
value = getattr(obj, "attribute")
```