# Construct Django Query with dynamic complex AND + OR structure

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-database

I need to query MyField for a list of language:country tuples. (

The SQL I want would be:

```
SELECT * FROM MyField WHERE
language=my_tuples[0][0] AND country=my_tuples[0][1] OR
language=my_tuples[1][0] AND country=my_tuples[1][1] OR
language=my_tuples[2][0] AND country=my_tuples[2][1] OR
...
```

I saw this similar question but couldn't quite get it to work: 
[Django: OR queries with dynamic field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340106/django-or-queries-with-dynamic-field-names)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with a bit of tinkering:

```
    qs = self.MyField.all()
    q = Q()

    for combination in my_tuples:
        q = q | Q(Q(language=combination['language']) & Q(country=combination['country']))

    return qs.filter(q)
```

Comment: Here is a one liner: `q = reduce(operator.or_, ((Q(language=lang) & Q(country=country)) for lang, country in my_tuples)) `